# Facing problem in running react native app

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator

Im beginner starting of with react native i am trying to run ios simulator for my react native and im getting the following error.

trying to run react native on ios simulator im face the folllowing error

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
› Opening on iOS...
xcrun exited with non-zero code: 2
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Unable to boot device because we cannot determine the runtime bundle.
No such file or directory

Comment: Did you try to open your project in XCode and run it? You will get a more speficic errir message.

Comment: its working. now thanks